# Where should I put my deployment tasks when using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano to deploy apps that I'm building in Sinatra and Rails. For a while now I've been writing all the stuff I need to get done during the deployment right into `config/deploy.rb`. It looks like I'm just writing Rake here. I was wondering if I could get some advice on if I'm putting these in the right place or if I could be more "Capistranorish" with my deployments.

Here are a few examples of things I'm doing here. I write pretty much everything that I need my deployments to do here.

```
# deploy.rb
task :initctl_reload_configuration do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
    execute "sudo initctl reload-configuration"
  end
end

task :rebuild_sitemap_no_ping do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
    execute "cd /srv/app/#{environment}/current && RAILS_ENV=#{environment} bundle exec rake sitemap:refresh:no_ping"
  end
end

task :rebuild_sitemap do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
    execute "cd /srv/app/#{environment}/current && RAILS_ENV=#{environment} bundle exec rake sitemap:refresh"
  end
end

task :restart_services do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
    execute "sudo service tomcat6 restart"
    execute "sudo service sunspot-solr restart"
    execute "sudo service app-#{environment} restart"
    execute "sudo service nginx restart"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all you got, it might be just fine leaving it in `deploy.rb`.

If you really want to move those tasks somewhere, below contents of `Capfile` (you likely have it in the root of your project) should give you a hint:

```
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

So just create a file in `lib/capistrano/tasks/` ending with `.rake` and that should do it!

Comment: Awesome advice! Thank you! I'm definitely going to end up with a lot more stuff that I'll need to better organize. So moving into that directory and breaking up into separate Rake tasks will help.